# Master page changes without reason or person?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

Platform SharePoint 2010: I have problem with master pages changing without obvious reason. At the same farm there is 5 site collections and the newest site collection is set up from a other site collection with it's own master pages and so on.

In this new site collection master page changes time to time to set up site collection master page without anyone changing it in changemasterpage.aspx.

Has anyone had this kind of strange mishap?

Answer (score 1):

This must be user error, SharePoint is not going to revert to an old master page without the being set in SharePoint Designer or via the browser. Do you have a feature that may be setting this?